# How do you include the Post ID within the_content() field in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Please bear with me on this question. I understand that it may not be as clear but and suggestions are helpful.

So I created a template page and within that template page I have two tags.

One field is the default:

```
 <?php the_content(); ?>
```

and the other one is

```
<?php the_field('test_advertisement_two', 25017); ?>
```

that I created using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) which includes the Post id. How can I include the post id in the `<?php the_content(); ?>` field?

I think I maybe confused how `<?php the_content(); ?>` works. Is there a way to assign a name to it a name to it?

This is what I am doing:

I am calling the template page (test-template.php) that contains:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php the_field('test_advertisement_two', 25017); ?>
```

from a different location by using

The post content in `<?php the_field('test_advertisement_two', 25017); ?>` displays but the content from `<?php the_content(); ?>` does not display. That's why I figure that I either need to include a post Id in `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Comment: What do you mean by "in the tag"? Can't you just do `<?php the_content(); the_field('test_advertisement_two', 25017); ?>`

Comment: Let me rephrase that.  I would like to include the post ID in the field name `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Comment: I'm still not able to make sense of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not sure how clear I can make it. "Trying to make sense of what I am trying to do" is pretty vague. You asked me what I meant by "in the tag" and I clarified with the correct name field. You then combined the field name and the content field test_advertisement_two. But I don't why

Comment: Your edit makes it clearer, thanks. Answer coming.

Answer (score 1):

> The post content in  displays but the content from  does not display. That's why I figure that I either need to include a post Id in

Essentially.

`the_content` only functions right within [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), one of the most important concepts in WordPress. The `the_field` call is working because it's being explicitly passed a post ID in the optional second parameter.

You'll need to access it like this:

```
$page = get_post(25017);
echo $page->post_content;
```

(or `get_page` if you're on a page instead of a post)

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you need post content using post id then below is the code for that.

```
echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
```